# Command Line Tools - XCode 5.0.1 not appearing and unavailable

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line-tool

I've been trying many different ways of installing Command Line Tools to XCode and nothing seems to work. I've tried going on to the Developer Site and installing it from there, I've tried dragging and dropping the .pkg directly into the directory, that obviously didn't work and I've tried using the Terminal command xcode-select --install, and this also doesn't work. I've also tried downgrading to older versions of XCode, I also tried upgrading the OS to Mountain Lion and Mavericks and this didn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I did this shortly after upgrading to mavricks by downloading 'Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October' from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action   When you say it doesn't work... what actually happens?

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, it doesn't appear in the Download panel of the Preference window, so I assume it hasn't been downloaded / installed properly. I also suspect that it hasn't worked because when I open up another coding program, such as Code Blocks, there are no compilers to choose from, which I assume is linked to this same issue.

Edit: The xcode-select --install command in terminal brings up a software update window as would be expected, goes through licensing aggrements etc, but when the progress bar appear, it gets to about 33% and then declares that the software is "unavailable"

Comment: I see the same thing. Command line tools are reported as unavailable at around 33% completion.

Comment: Hi.  I found this because Im having the issue where i downloaded XcodeCLT from an apple download link. So i just ran that code xcode-select --install and I got the license agreement, clicked on it...I get a Finding Software window and then Cant install the software because it is not currently available from the Update Server